# Unity InjectionConstructor in Web.config

Tags: c#, unity-container, web-config

In Unity, what is the Web.config equivalent of the following C# code:

```
container
    .RegisterType<IRepositoryProvider, RepositoryProvider>(
        new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(new object[] { new RepositoryFactories() })
    );
```

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
<register type="Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Factories.IRepositoryProvider, Repository.Pattern.Ef6" mapTo="Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Factories.RepositoryProvider, Repository.Pattern.Ef6">
    <lifetime type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.PerRequestLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc" />
    <constructor>
        <param name="repositoryFactories" value="new object[]{new RepositoryFactories()}"/>
    </constructor>
</register>
```

The difficult part is how to handle "new object[]{new RepositoryFactories()}".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your config is not quite right. You need the dependency attr. See my sample below it works.

**Unity Config:**

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<namespace name="ConsoleApplication8" />
<assembly name="ConsoleApplication8" />
<container name="MyContainer">
  <types>
    <type type="ConsoleApplication8.IRepositoryFactories, ConsoleApplication8"
           mapTo="ConsoleApplication8.RepositoryFactories, 
           ConsoleApplication8" />
    <type type="ConsoleApplication8.IRepositoryProvider, ConsoleApplication8"
           mapTo="ConsoleApplication8.RepositoryProvider, ConsoleApplication8"
           name="RepositoryProvider" >
      <lifetime type="singleton" />
      <constructor>
        <param name="factories">
          <dependency />
        </param>
      </constructor>
    </type>
  </types>
</container>
```

*Probably don't need the fully qualified name as the assembly name and the namespace has been registered.*

**Types:**

```
public interface IRepositoryProvider
{}

public class RepositoryProvider : IRepositoryProvider
{
    private IRepositoryFactories _factories;
    private string _name;

    public RepositoryProvider(IRepositoryFactories factories) {
        _factories = factories;
    }

    public RepositoryProvider(string name) {
        _name = name;
    }
}

public interface IRepositoryFactories { }

public class RepositoryFactories : IRepositoryFactories{}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.LoadConfiguration("MyContainer");

        var instance = container.
                           Resolve<IRepositoryProvider>("RepositoryProvider");
    }
}
```